# Performing gradient-based optimization with intermediate discrete variables in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

We have a user who wants to solve an optimization problem that has intermediate discrete variables using a gradient-based method. They're running into [this error](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/45d6e641fa01aa447402b89a2de2c42cc0102c13/openmdao/core/total_jac.py#L212). I know we could restructure the problem to not use discrete variables, but could I also treat this error as a warning given that the discrete variable doesn't change? Or is there a fundamental reason that the derivs wouldn't propagate correctly. To be clear, we're using approx_totals at the model level.

Here is a small test case exhibiting this:

```py
import openmdao.api as om
import numpy as np


class DiscreteComp(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('a', 2.)
        self.add_discrete_output('b', val=0)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs, discrete_inputs, discrete_outputs):
        discrete_outputs['b'] = 2 * inputs['a']
        
class DummyComp(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('a', 2.)
        self.add_discrete_input('b', 1)
        self.add_output('c')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs, discrete_inputs, discrete_outputs):
        b = discrete_inputs['b']
        outputs['c'] = inputs['a']**2 * b

prob = om.Problem()

prob.model.add_subsystem('discrete_comp', DiscreteComp(), promotes=['*'])
prob.model.add_subsystem('dummy_comp', DummyComp(), promotes=['*'])

prob.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('a', lower=-10, upper=10)
prob.model.add_objective('c')

prob.model.approx_totals()

prob.setup()

# run the optimization
prob.run_driver()
```

which gives this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 39, in <module>
    prob.run_driver()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/weis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 685, in run_driver
    return self.driver.run()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/weis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py", line 480, in run
    raise self._exc_info
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/weis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py", line 643, in _gradfunc
    sens_dict = self._compute_totals(of=self._quantities,
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/weis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/driver.py", line 892, in _compute_totals
    total_jac = _TotalJacInfo(problem, of, wrt, use_abs_names,
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/weis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/total_jac.py", line 209, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Total derivative %s '%s' depends upon "
RuntimeError: Total derivative with respect to '_auto_ivc.v0' depends upon discrete output variables ['discrete_comp.b'].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, there is a reason that OpenMDAO raises this error. Discrete outputs are not passed through the same data system as continuous one. Only the continuous outputs have access to the derivative system. While it is possible to have this intermediate discrete variable here, and take a finite-difference over the whole thing, you only get away with it because you really have a continuous calculation there.

If the output had been really discrete, then its not mathematically valid to take a derivative or make finite-difference approximation across the compute. This is why OpenMDAO raises the error.

There are admittedly some corner cases where you could argue that OpenMDAO should let you do this. For example if your output `c` was computed as:
`outputs['c'] = floor(inputs['a'])`
and you knew that you would limit the value of `a` to between 1 and 2. You know that `c` would always be exactly 1. Hence you could say that its valid to differentiate across this since the discrete variable never changes in value and hence the function is differentiable within these bounds.

If you wanted to use OpenMDAO to finite difference this you have two options:

1. Even though it's a discrete value, list it as a continuous one anyway. This works around OpenMDAO's validity check, but its totally up to you to make sure the values are really never changing with the ranges you are taking derivatives around. If you decide to implement analytic derivatives, simply don't declare one for the discrete output with respect to anything.
2. Move the discrete calculations into the `setup` phase and pass the information around as options. This forces you to absolutely respect the "never changes" paradigm since setup only happens once. It does require some redesign.
3. If you don't like OpenMDAO's nanny-ing you can always comment out the error :) You obviously do this at your own risk ... but thats one of the values of open source software!

My personal recommendation is option #2. This is really the best overall design, and forces you to be sure the discrete calculations never change during an opt.

Comment: Thanks, Justin! This is a really helpful walkthrough on possible solutions.